# ESTA 90 day travel visa waiver

Tags: usa, esta

I am flying to the US on Monday, initially it had only meant to be a 6 week stay.  But no I expect it to be the full 90 days or slightly less. My ESTA has already been approved, so do I need to change my return flight now before departure, or can I change it once I am within the US.?

Simply what I am asking is, Can I stay in the US for up to 90 days, or will my flight schedule dictate how long I can stay in the US?

Comment: Be sure to not make it 91 days. That gets you in trouble later.

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule, all VWP travelers get admitted for 90 days, no matter which precise plans they put in their ESTA applications, or even what they *say* their plans are at the immigration interview.

Exceptions are *possible*, but will only happen if there's something *extremely specific to you personally* that worries the immigration officer, not simply based on changing plans since you filled out the ESTA form.

Once issued, an ESTA stays valid for two years, and you're specifically not required to key in new details (dates, destinations, addresses) when your plans change.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Having contacted my airline, flight change costs are extremely expensive. it would be much cheaper to pay one way direct out of the US once I get there